# AngularJS + Firebase Upload profile image

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase

I have a JavaScript image uploader which will upload an image and give me the image src. I need to save this value in my FireBase DB for the current user being created.

I tried outputting the img.src to a hidden input but that didn't seem to work. Like so:

```
$('.userImageValue').val(img.src);

<input class="userImageValue" ng-model="data.userImage" style="display: none;">
```

**I just figured out if I change the value once it is added to the invisible input it works. So how can I best make the input "register" after the src value is inserted?**

Here is the controller where a new user is created.

```
  $scope.list = $firebaseArray(new Firebase("https://my-db.firebaseio.com/users"));

  // Create user button  
  $scope.add_new_user = function() {
    console.log($scope.data);
    $scope.list.$add($scope.data);
    $scope.data = {};
  }
```

This is an input on the page which currently works with the above code and saves a new field for the current user being created.

```
<input id="firstname" type="text" ng-model="data.firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
```

**This is the part I am stuck on** I need to save the value of **img.src** from the code below as a new field in the FireBase DB for the user currently being created.

```
  var userImageUploader = document.getElementById('userImageUploader');

  userImageUploader.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var file = userImageUploader.files[0];
    var imageType = /image.*/;

    if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = reader.result;

      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  });
```

I hope that makes sense and thank you in advanced!

Comment: The "registering" isn't working because you're using jquery to insert the value into an input bound to a scope variable. I think this question / some varieties of it have been answered before, I'll try to find some examples.

Comment: Here is the same symptom in another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29143088/1526037)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using Parse for the image portion.

1) it also has a free tier but with much larger storage than the firebase free tier, which will quickly be exhausted by images.
2) it has better tools for images imo.

Comment: This answer isn't really relevant to this question since @BtrCSowl isn't storing the actual image files on Firebase, but rather the src urls of the images. Firebase is a nosql database (key/value), not an object storage service. Meaning you can't directly store image files in Firebase. You can, however, store _plenty_ of images in Firebase as base64 encoded strings. However, it takes a small bit of time to convert an image to a base64 string, and then back again, so that's not be the best way to go about it.