# AngualrJS + Firebase pre-populated input not saving to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase

I have an AngularJS app with a Firebase database. I have a page with form fields and a click event $scope.add_new = function() { which will add all data inputed into the fields to my database.

However I am pre-populating one of the input fields with var x:

```
var x = "hello world";
$('#test').val(x);    
<input type="text" id="test" ng-model="data.test">
```

But the value in the input isn't setting to Firebase unless I manually type in the field. It seems not to register if I enter a value with Javascript.

Here is my controller with the click event to create a new array list with the input values

```
$scope.list = $firebaseArray(new Firebase("https://my-db.firebaseio.com/users"));

$scope.add_new = function() {
  $scope.list.$add($scope.data);
  $scope.data = {};
  $route.reload();
}
```

Any help is much appericated.

Comment: Why would you want to update your input outside of angular in plain javascript? Anyway, I guess this happens because angular knows nothing about your update and it needs a digest cycle to [apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) values. So, you could somehow call your script inside `$scope.$apply()` method or better just update your input from within angular controller using your `data.test` model.

Comment: Why would you use jQuery to prepopulate the data when you could just set `data.test = "hello world"`

Comment: Hi Luke! As you can tell from the challenges here, this looks like a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). You may want to start with the use case and problem you're trying to solve as there's probably a much simpler way than the solution you're attempting to implement.